# Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Tags: java, java-6, smartfoxserver

I am trying install SmartFoxServer 2X in ubuntu, but during installation I have this error

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Debian Squeeze install. something to do with the supplied jre... i changed the startup scripts to point to my installed $JAVA_HOME/jre

Comment: Once you get it going, and if you are trying to access on another machine, you can alter config/server.xml to access it 'remotely' :)
You might also need about 1Gb of RAM or so :)